# flutter: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null. how to solve this warning

Tags: flutter, dart

**after flutter upgrading i am facing this warning and i did no find proper solution**

```
C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/persistent-tab-view.widget.dart:368:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/292

You can use [persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2) package instead.

If you want to use current package then you have to modify library file.

Replace,

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_))
```

To,

```
WidgetsBinding?.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_))
```